Selenium on Twitter Log In (Username prompt issue)
I'm doing 100 days of Python on Udemy and I'm halfway through (day 51).
The goal of this project is to get the upload and download from speedtest.net. Afterwards, I need to log in to www.x.com (twitter) then tweet the internet provider whether it's been doing great or poorly.
I have one niggle that I need help in. Whenever I log in, perhaps because of the bot, after entering the email, it asks for the username. Even with the code to enter the username, it doesn't work. What works, however, is for me to open the INSPECTOR, which somehow triggers it back to the sign in page, enters the email, password, then continues on without a hitch.
Is there any workaround to stop myself from having to open the INSPECTOR tool to proceed? Here's my code below:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import time

load_dotenv()

# -------------------------- CONSTANTS --------------------------#

PROMISED_DOWN = 25
PROMISED_UP = 25
X_EMAIL = os.getenv("X_EMAIL")
X_PASSWORD = os.getenv("X_PASSWORD")
X_USERNAME = os.getenv("X_USERNAME")
INTERNET_PROVIDER =  os.getenv("INTERNET_PROVIDER")


# ---------------------------- BODY ----------------------------#

class InternetSpeedTwitterBot:
    SPEEDTEST_URL = "https://www.speedtest.net"
    X_URL = "https://www.x.com"

    def __init__(self):
        self.chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        self.chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=self.chrome_options)
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(1)

        self.up = 0
        self.down = 0

        # self.up_speed, self.down_speed = 50, 50  # debugger
        self.down_speed, self.up_speed = self.get_internet_speed()

    def get_internet_speed(self):
        self.driver.get(self.SPEEDTEST_URL)

        start_button = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".start-text")
        start_button.click()

        time.sleep(30)

        # Grab the new values
        self.down = self.driver.find_element(
            By.CSS_SELECTOR,
            ".result-data-large.number.result-data-value.download-speed")
        self.up = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".result-data-large.number.result-data-value.upload-speed")

        # While the up text has not yet come out
        while self.up.text == "—":
            self.down = self.driver.find_element(  # Once up text is --, down is done testing. Store value
                By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                ".result-data-large.number.result-data-value.download-speed")
            time.sleep(1)  # Keep pausing the next line of code for 1 second until it's done

        print(self.down.text)
        print(self.up.text)
        return float(self.down.text), float(self.up.text)

    def log_in_twitter(self):
        self.driver.get(self.X_URL)
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 105)  # Wait up to 15 seconds

        time.sleep(3)

        try:
            x_sign_in = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
                                                               '//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[3]/a/div/span')))
            self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", x_sign_in)  # Scroll into view
            time.sleep(1)
            self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", x_sign_in)  # Use JS to click because can't access o therwise
            time.sleep(1)
            x_sign_in.click()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Failed to click sign in: {e}")

        # TODO Enter Email
        try:
            email = wait.until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
                                            '//*[@id="layers"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[4]/label/div/div[2]/div/input')))
            time.sleep(1)
            email.send_keys(X_EMAIL, Keys.ENTER)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Failed to type email: {e}")

        # TODO Enter Username if prompted -- THIS DOESN'T WORK! :(
        try:
            username = wait.until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
                                            '//*[@id="layers"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[4]/label/div/div[2]/div/input')))
            time.sleep(1)
            username.send_keys(X_USERNAME, Keys.ENTER)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Failed to type email: {e}")

        # TODO Enter Password
        try:
            password = wait.until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
                                            '//*[@id="layers"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/label/div/div[2]/div[1]/input')))
            time.sleep(1)
            password.send_keys(X_PASSWORD, Keys.ENTER)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Failed to type password: {e}")

        # TODO Click close 2FA if it asks for this
        try:
            close_2fa = wait.until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
                                        '//*[@id="layers"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/button')))
            time.sleep(1)
            close_2fa.click()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Failed to click on the close 2FA button: {e}")

        time.sleep(2)

    def tweet_at_provider(self):
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)  # Wait up to 10 seconds

        # TODO Set up the message
        if self.up_speed < 37 or self.down_speed < 37:
            tweet = (
                f"Hey @{INTERNET_PROVIDER}, why is my internet speed {self.down_speed} Mpbs down/{self.up_speed} Mpbs up when I pay for \""
                f"{PROMISED_DOWN} Mpbs down/{PROMISED_UP} Mbps up?")
        else:
            tweet = (f"Hey @{INTERNET_PROVIDER}, good job! My internet speed is {self.down_speed} Mbps down/{self.up_speed} Mbps up against \""
                     f"the promised speed of {PROMISED_DOWN} Mbps down/{PROMISED_UP} Mbps up!")


        # TODO Compose the tweet
        try:
            compose_tweet = wait.until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable(((By.XPATH,
                                             '//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div')))
            )
            time.sleep(1)
            compose_tweet.send_keys(tweet)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Failed to click on the close 2FA button: {e}")


        # TODO Click Post! :D
        try:
            send_tweet = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
                                                                '//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/button')))
            time.sleep(1)
            send_tweet.click()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Failed to click on the close 2FA button: {e}")


internet_speed_bot = InternetSpeedTwitterBot()
internet_speed_bot.log_in_twitter()
internet_speed_bot.tweet_at_provider()


What I have tried:

Create a try block to enter the username (which didn't work)

What worked manually:

Opening the Inspector Tool

What I want to happen:

Be able to put in the username if required

